# Parse strings as arguments to update ggplot theme()

Tags: r, ggplot2

The ultimate goal is to create a shiny app where the user input strings returned in the format "panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = 'red')" and a ggplot theme is updated. I am therefore trying to parse this string to update the theme.

This is the original plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rlang)
theme_set(theme_dark())
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class))+
  geom_point()
```

In this simplified example, I want to dynamically change the minor grid lines to red. This is what I have so far using `parse_expr()` and `eval_tidy()` which does not work. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rlang)
theme_set(theme_dark())

x <- "panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = 'red')"

theme_update(eval_tidy(parse_expr(x)))
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) +
  geom_point()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of Twitter I found a solution!

Single argument (panel.grid.minor)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rlang)
theme_set(theme_dark())
x <- "theme_update(panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = 'red'))"
eval_tidy(parse_expr(x))
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) +
  geom_point()
```

Multiple arguments (panel.grid.minor & panel.background)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rlang)
theme_set(theme_dark())
x <- "theme_update(panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = 'red'), panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'cyan'))"
eval_tidy(parse_expr(x))
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) +
  geom_point()
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different option without `rlang` is using the base `eval` and `parse` option like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_dark())

x <- "theme_update(panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = 'red'))"
eval(parse(text = x))
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>